# Gstreamer adding dynamic demuxer element chains

Tags: python, gstreamer

We have multiple cameras that send muxed RTP and RTCP to the same port of a video processor. In this example I just use raw video frames to make it simple, later it will be H.264 that I hope to decode on the GPU.

With gst-launch I get it to work:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtpbin name=rtpbin funnel name=frtp videotestsrc pattern=ball is-live=true ! "video/x-raw,framerate=10/1" ! rtpvrawpay ssrc=10 ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! frtp.sink_0 rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! frtp.sink_1 frtp.src ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000

gst-launch-1.0 -v rtpssrcdemux name=rtpdemux udpsrc name=udpsrc port=5000 ! rtpdemux.sink rtpdemux.src_10 ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)RGBA, depth=(string)10, width=(string)320, height=(string)240, colorimetry=(string)BT601-5, payload=(int)96" ! rtpvrawdepay ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Likewise if I in the python code use the same string and parse it with `Gst.parse_launch` it works, in the case I have set the ssrc at the sender since that is part of the pad name on the demuxer.

But when I try to build the chain in python dynamically it fails. Any suggestions on how to solve this? Here is my test code:

```
import gi
import time
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst


class Video():

    def __init__(self, port=5000):
        Gst.init(None)

        self.port = port

        # UDP video mux stream (:5000)
        self.launch_pipline = [ 'rtpssrcdemux name=rtpdemux',
                               f'udpsrc name=udpsrc port={port}',
                                '! rtpdemux.sink', 
                            #     'rtpdemux.src_10'
                            #     '! application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)RAW,sampling=(string)RGBA,depth=(string)10,width=(string)320,height=(string)240,colorimetry=(string)BT601-5,payload=(int)96', 
                            #     '! rtpvrawdepay name=depay ! videoconvert', 
                            #    f'! appsink name=appsink{port} emit-signals=true sync=false max-buffers=0 drop=true'
                            ]
        self.start_gst(self.launch_pipline)

    def start_gst(self, config):
        command = ' '.join(config)
        print(command)
        self.video_pipe = Gst.parse_launch(command)
        self.video_pipe.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        self.demuxer = self.video_pipe.get_by_name('rtpdemux')
        self.demuxer.connect("pad-added", self._demuxer_new_pad)
        bus = self.video_pipe.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        bus.connect("message::error", self._on_error)
        bus.connect("message::eos", self._on_eos)
        self.app_sink = {}
        #------
        # app_sink = self.video_pipe.get_by_name(f'appsink{self.port}')
        # app_sink.connect('new-sample', self._new_frame)

    def _on_error(self, _, message):
        err, debug = message.parse_error()
        print("Error: %s" % err, debug)

    def _on_eos(self, _, message):
        print("EOF!")

    def _demuxer_new_pad(self, demuxer, pad):
        name = pad.get_name()
        print(f"---------\n{demuxer}\n{pad}\n{name}\n-------")
        is_rtcp = name.startswith("rtcp")
        sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("appsink", f"appsink_{name}")
        sink.set_property("emit-signals", True)
        sink.set_property("sync", False)
        sink.set_property("max-buffers", 0)
        sink.set_property("drop", True)
        if not is_rtcp:
            sink.connect('new-sample', self._new_frame)
        self.video_pipe.add(sink)
        self.app_sink[name] = sink
        if is_rtcp:
            chain_pad = sink.get_static_pad("sink")
        else:
            # caps = Gst.caps_from_string("application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)RAW,sampling=(string)RGBA,depth=(string)10,width=(string)320,height=(string)240,colorimetry=(string)BT601-5,payload=(int)96")
            depay = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtpvrawdepay")
            # depay_pad = depay.get_static_pad("sink")
            # depay_pad.set_caps(caps)
            # pad.set_caps(caps)
            convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert")
            self.video_pipe.add(depay)
            self.video_pipe.add(convert)
            chain_pad = depay.get_static_pad("sink")
            depay.link(convert)
            convert.link(sink)
        pad.link(chain_pad)

    def _new_frame(self, sink):
        print("in video_udp callback")
        sample = sink.emit('pull-sample')
        caps = sample.get_caps()
        name = sink.get_name()
        print(f"caps: {caps}, name: {name}")
        # height = caps.get_structure(0).get_value('height')
        # width = caps.get_structure(0).get_value('width')
        # got_buf = sample.get_buffer() is not None
        # print(f"{height}x{width} {got_buf}")
        return Gst.FlowReturn.OK

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the video object
    # Add port= if is necessary to use a different one
    video = Video(port=5000)
    time.sleep(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I missed that any new elements added to a pipeline needs to be set to playing. I had miss-read the documentation that indicated that all elements of a pipeline are in the same state. Here are the changes that make it work:

```
    def _demuxer_new_pad(self, demuxer, pad):
        name = pad.get_name()
        print(f"---------\n{demuxer}\n{pad}\n{name}\n-------")
        is_rtcp = name.startswith("rtcp")
        sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("appsink", f"appsink_{name}")
        sink.set_property("emit-signals", True)
        sink.set_property("sync", False)
        sink.set_property("max-buffers", 0)
        sink.set_property("drop", True)
        if not is_rtcp:
            sink.connect('new-sample', self._new_frame)
        self.video_pipe.add(sink)
        self.app_sink[name] = sink
        if is_rtcp:
            chain_pad = sink.get_static_pad("sink")
            pad.link(chain_pad)
            sink.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        else:
            caps = Gst.caps_from_string("application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)RAW,sampling=(string)RGBA,depth=(string)10,width=(string)320,height=(string)240,colorimetry=(string)BT601-5,payload=(int)96")
            depay = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtpvrawdepay")
            pad.set_caps(caps) # gives warning, but ok
            convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert")
            self.video_pipe.add(depay)
            self.video_pipe.add(convert)
            chain_pad = depay.get_static_pad("sink")
            depay.link(convert)
            convert.link(sink)
            pad.link(chain_pad)
            depay.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
            convert.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
            sink.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
```